# Searching table for null values

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I trying to search my `users` table to determine whether the field `token` is NULL or not (indicating whether the user activated, confirmed or not).

I am using CakePHP 1.3 and am having some problem with PHP coding.

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'User' => array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'User.token LIKE' =>
                'IS'.($this->data['User']['activated'] == 'yes' ? '' : 'NOT') . ' NULL'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: What result does the above code produce and how does this differ from your expectation?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with cakephp syntax. but `'NULL'` is not `NULL` or `""`value. it is a string.

try using `''` instead

Answer (score 0):

I would advise expanding that condition code, as it's hard to read. Or just arrange it a bit differently.

Currently, you'll end up with `User.token LIKE IS NULL` or `User.token LIKE NULL`, and neither of those will work with regular SQL.  CakePHP is smart enough to recognise equality or inequality with nulls, so you could do the following:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'User' => array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'User.token ' . 
                $this->data['User']['activated'] == 'yes' ? '' : '!=' 
                => NULL 
        )
));
```

Essentially, this determines what operator to use, depending on User.activated.  A value of yes results in equality with null, otherwise inequality with null, and CakePHP will correctly result in `User.token IS NULL` or `User.token IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

### IS NULL is not "LIKE 'IS NULL'"

The syntax in the question is quite confusing - it's a like condition, yet you don't want a like condition. What the code in the question will do is construct a query that will effectively match the string "IS NULL" like so:

```
WHERE `User`.`token` LIKE "IS NULL"
```

To search for null values - construct a condition using null:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'User' => array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'User.token' => NULL
        )
    )
);
```

This will generate a query containing the condition:

```
WHERE `User`.`token` IS NULL
```